# Is it possible to pull in Previous & Next data using querySelector?

Tags: javascript, windows-8

Here is my code:

```
WinJS.xhr({ url: urlText })
            .then(function complete(xml) {

                var restXML = xml.responseXML;
                var items = xml.responseXML.querySelectorAll("item");
                for (var i = 0 ; i < items.length ; i++) {
                    var item = items[i];
                    title = items[i].querySelector("title").textContent;
                    dataList.push({ title: title });
```

What I am trying to do is get the previous and next titles in the same dataList.push.

Is this even possible?

Also, how would I stop it from producing an error on the first title as that has no previous entry?

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: You mean `items[i-1].…` and `items[i+1].…` by "previous" and "next"?

Comment: The code you posted only will yield an error if there is no `<title>` element in the `item`. Please show your actual code where you try to get the previous entry.

Comment: Sorry. Everything I attempted I checked with the debugger and nothing has worked so I removed my attempts. I have tried as you say with the + and - but it returns "Variable undefined in strict mode".

Comment: You need to show us your attempts so we can help you correct them and *learn*. Of course we could also present you a solution, but SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: The only reason I presented it the way I did was because I thought it wasn't possible. I am new to JS for sure and I still have lots to learn, I will do as you say next time and explain what I have tried. Sorry for causing offence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var prevTitle = i > 0 ? items[i - 1].querySelector("title").textContent : '';
var nextTitle = i < items.length - 1 ? items[i + 1].querySelector("title").textContent : '';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rodrigo. I get -> "Variable undefined in strict mode" when I try this though.

Comment: then use `var prevTitle...`

Comment: Thank you! Wow, (slaps head) I should of posted hours ago ^_^

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `i < items.length-1`?